# C++ Problems with splitting code into multiple files

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

So, I am working on a project and decided to split the code into multiple files as it was getting too big. However, a got a compilation error. I managed to recreate the error in this simple case:

```
//main.cpp
#include<iostream>
#include "classa.h"
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

The main does nothing it just includes classa.h

```
//classa.h
#ifndef CLASSA_H_INCLUDED
#define CLASSA_H_INCLUDED
#include<vector>
using namespace std;
vector<int> primes= {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
class classa
{
private:
    int a;
public:
    int getA();
    void setA(int newA);
};

#endif //CLASSA_H_INCLUDED
```

The class isn't even necessary for the error to occur. However, I wanted to have something in classa.cpp

```
//classa.cpp
#include "classa.h"
using namespace std;
int classa::getA()
{
    return a;
}
void classa::setA(int newA)
{
    a=newA;
}
```

It gives me the following error:

```
obj\Debug\sources\main.o:main.cpp:(.bss+0x0): multiple definition of `primes'
obj\Debug\sources\classa.o:classa.cpp:(.bss+0x0): first defined here
```

The problem is that unlike here in my project I cannot use some sort of constant or a define for the global variables as they are things that can be modified by different classes.

Comment: 1. Don't use `using namespace` here, it's evil. 2. A vector of prime numbers should probably be `const`.

Comment: ...and not a vector! A `const array[]` or `std::array<T, n> const` seems better (no dynamic allocation, no #include in the former case) when the # elements is fixed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make primes an `extern` variable, and declare it in your `classa.h` header, but only defined it once in `classa.cpp`.

Currently, as your compiler told you, primes exists twice, in `main.cpp` and in `classa.cpp`. Keep in mind, `#include` is merely text substitution.

classa.h:

```
 extern std::vector<int> const primes;
```

classa.cpp:

```
std::vector<int> const primes = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
```

Read more about storage class specifiers [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration).

Comment: If the number of elements is fixed, why use a `vector`? A bare or `std::array` would avoid unnecessary dynamic allocation (theoretical overhead) and, in the former case, header inclusion.

Comment: I agree, but it wasn't part of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

If you have .cpp file in overall - then it makes sense to split into

Into .h file:

```
extern std::vector<int> primes;
```

Into .cpp file:

```
using namespace std;
vector<int> const primes = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
```

"using namespace std" might cause conflicts between 3rd party libraries, but this occurs very rarely - I prefer to use "using namespace std" whenever possible. But if there are conflicts - then you might want to localized "using namespace std" into your own .cpp file. (Where you control what #include's that file has).

But sometimes you might not have .cpp file at all (e.g. only local inline functions or template classes) - then you can initialize vector like this:

```
__declspec(selectany) std::vector<int> primes = {1,2,3,5,7,11,13,17,19};
```

This will instruct linker to pick up only one copy (some of them), and discard everything else. This does not play well if you want to #ifdef some of initialization, but this is not normal use case anyway.

I prefer not to use const ever, because it's always pain in neck to get const right after 2-3 level conversions. I write in function comments what is input / what is output and what should not be modified. (Because that one can change over iterations)